# setpgid for Child Process: No Such Process

Tags: c, unix, operating-system

I'm not sure why I get such error on my computer. I've tested the code on some other computers. It works well.

If I remove `sleep(2)`, it works. I think I should be able to set the PGID for the zombie process. Does it depend on OS implementation?

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define CHECK(syscall, msg) do {                    \
    if ((syscall) == -1) {                          \
      perror(msg);                                  \
      _exit(1);                                     \
    }                                               \
  } while(0)

#define SAFE_CLOSE_NOT_STD(fd) do {                                 \
    if (fd != STDIN_FILENO && fd != STDOUT_FILENO && fd != -1) {    \
      CHECK(close(fd), "close error");                              \
      fd = -1;                                                      \
    }                                                               \
  } while(0)

int main () {
  int ls_pid;
  char *ls_argv[] = { "ls", NULL };

  CHECK(ls_pid = fork(), "fork error");
  if (!ls_pid) {
    CHECK(setpgid(0, 0), "child setpgid error");
    CHECK(execvp(ls_argv[0], ls_argv), "execve error");
  } else {
    printf("child pid:%d\n", ls_pid);
    sleep(2); // no error arises if I remove this line
    CHECK(setpgid(ls_pid, ls_pid), "setpgid error"); // error here
  }
  CHECK(wait(NULL), "wait error");

  printf("Finish\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when `sleep` occurs while `parents` executing it switches to `child` process and in child process `execvp` replace current process with new one and it's get exited. When it comes back to parent after `2 seconds` child process is not in existence  that why `setpgid` fails.

```
CHECK(setpgid(ls_pid, ls_pid), "setpgid error");
```

As you can see from the man page of `setpgid`, Its an `EACCES` error

*An attempt was made to change the process group  ID  of
              one  of  the  children  of  the calling process and the
              **child had already performed  an  execve(2)  (setpgid()**,
              setpgrp()).*

Comment: Suppose I change the PGID of child process before it exits. Now the child process and parent process have different PGID. Which one is the foreground group?

Comment: At any  time,  only one of the process groups in the session can be the
foreground process  group  for  the  terminal;  the  remaining process  groups  are in the background.

Answer (score 1):

You get an error when you sleep because the child process has exited and no longer exists.  You can’t do anything to a zombie process except call `wait`.